# angularJS - iterating through JSON object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a nested JSON "object" called znanja that I want to display on my webpage. It will contain a number of values that I want to make into a list. Basically I'm building a portfolio and want to list my skills. So far I've managed to display the title, and the whole object, or by calling a specific one (for instance `{{ znanje.ena }}`), but I can't figure out how to display them without the attribute name. If I only call `{{ znanje }}`, I get them listed like in the JSON. Is there a angularJS directive I can do this with? I'm new to angular, so any help is appreciated.

my view:

```
<div ng-repeat="skill in skills">
    <h1>{{ skill.title }}</h1>
    <p ng-repeat="znanje in skill.znanja">{{ znanje }}</p>
</div>
```

my data:

```
  $scope.skills = [
  {
      title: "Code Knowledge",
      znanja : [{
        ena : "Javascript",
        dva : "HTML",
        tri : "CSS",
        stiri : "SASS"
      }]
  },
  {
      title: "Base Code Knowledge",
      znanja : [{
        ena : "Java",
        dva : "PhP"
      }]
  },
  {
      title: "Data",
      znanja : [{
        ena : "MongoDB",
        dva : "MySQL"
      }]
  }
  ];
```

PS: I've named the znanja attributes ena, dva, tri, stiri instead of 1, 2, 3, 4 to be able to call them in the html.

Comment: Should note that is a javascript object, not a json object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object which you wanted to apply a loop is nothing but the 1st element in  `znanja` array, so you should be specify `skill.znanja[0]` instead of `skill.znanja`.

By doing this you `ng-repeat` will iterate through each property of object and `{{znanje}}` will print the value of each property of `znanja[0]`

**Markup**

```
<div ng-repeat="skill in skills">
    <h1>{{ skill.title }}</h1>
    <p ng-repeat="znanje in skill.znanja[0]">{{ znanje }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

> It is possible to get ngRepeat to iterate over the properties of an
>   object using the following syntax:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in skill.znanja"> ... </div>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Answer (score 1):

In order to display the attributes you need a DOM element and a DOM element need a specific value to render so You have to manual at least for one iteration specifically call attributes.
How ever if you have any repetitions you can include it using ***ng-repeat*** like you have done.

That is if you want to display each attribute on the html page individually and later want to access it but if you just want to show as **json** object that will be as easy as passing the **json**

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-repeat="skill in skills">
    <h1>{{ skill.title }}</h1>
    <p ng-repeat="(key,value) in skill.znanja[0]">{{key}} <b>:</b> {{value}}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

(tested) combined both znanja-object 0 and the value:

```
    <div ng-repeat="skill in skills">
    <h1>{{ skill.title }}</h1>

    <p ng-repeat="(key, value) in skill.znanja[0] ">{{ value }}</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and best way to solve this issue is by changing your data structure. Simply remove the wrapping array around the lists you iterate on, turning them into object map:

```
$scope.skills = [
{
  title: "Code Knowledge",
  znanja : {
    ena : "Javascript",
    dva : "HTML",
    tri : "CSS",
    stiri : "SASS"
  }
},
{
  title: "Base Code Knowledge",
  znanja : {
    ena : "Java",
    dva : "PhP"
  }
},
{
  title: "Data",
  znanja : {
    ena : "MongoDB",
    dva : "MySQL"
  }
}
];
```

If you did not intend to use that array in any way (all examples contain only one element), then there's no reason for having it there.

There's no need to change anything in your original ng-repeat that way.